# Bug in Doctrine or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have the following code to update an object in database.

```
public function update($url, $projectId) {
    $conn = ConnectionPool::getConnection();

    $project = $conn->getReference('Project', $projectId);
    $url->setProject($project);

    //only works with this workaround
    //this do nothing, only call a random method in the referenced object
    $project->getName(); #workaround

    $conn->merge($url);
    $conn->flush();
}
```

If I remove the `#workaround` line, the element isn't updatet, but with it, the update works correctly. This is a bug or there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Where is `$url` coming from in this case?

Comment: @zi42 The $url is the object that will be updated. It has a OneToOne reference to the Project.

Comment: I mean, where are you getting it from? Did you `unserialize` it from somewhere? Did you get it as the result of some `find*` operation?

Comment: @zi42 No, I created it from the user input in interface without the use of `find` method. And after that, I add the reference to this object.

Comment: If `$url` has never been saved before, you should use `persist` on it. And define the OneToOne relationship with Project to cascade the persist operation.

Comment: @zi42 It was saved before correctly with `persist`. When I edit, I load the data to a form and save it creating a new object with the `__construct()` method setting the new data, I get the reference and set the reference and update. I'm doing this wrong? Because it works if I use the workaround (but is a workaround, of course).

Comment: OK now I see what you're doing. I've never done it like that before, I would always load the entity thru `find()`.

What happens if you do the `merge` before the `setProject`? Does it save it then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11853/discussion-between-zi42-and-renato-dinhani-conceicao)

Comment: My guess is that if you want to do it this way, you need to do a persist() between the merge and flush.  Merge() doesn't create anything in the unit-of-work, it just tells the entitymanager to manage the entity.  That said, absent other considerations not mentioned, you should be using find() to load the $url before updating it, and code in some optimistic locking, so you can avoid the possibility of out-of-order updates.